# New command to change colour and shape of text in list

Tags: macros, itemize

I'm writing some notes and where I feel it's worth repeating notes that I've taken elsewhere, I'd like to show that those particular notes are old notes that I (hopefully!) already know.

I settled on a light grey italic font.

I thought it would be a good idea to define a new command for the job - after all, is that not the LaTeX way?

Nothing fancy, just:

```latex
\newcommand{\existingnotes}[1]{\textit{\textcolor{gray}{#1}}}
```

The problem is, I'm presenting my notes as bullet points and that's where things get tricky.

This:

```latex
\begin{itemize}
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  \existingnotes{%
    \item Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
    nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.%
  }
  \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
  dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
\end{itemize}
```

Works:

[image]

This:

```latex
\begin{itemize}
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Curabitur pretium tincidunt lacus. Nulla gravida orci a odio. Nullam
    varius, turpis et commodo pharetra, est eros bibendum elit, nec luctus magna
    felis sollicitudin mauris.
  \end{itemize}
  \existingnotes{%
    \item Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
    nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.%
  }
  \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
  dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
\end{itemize}
```

Doesn't:

[image]

I'm sure I don't need to explain that if my command is used immediately after a nested `itemize`d list, it introduces excessive vertical space.

Obviously what you want to do is just use some nice switches:

```latex
\begin{itemize}
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Curabitur pretium tincidunt lacus. Nulla gravida orci a odio. Nullam
    varius, turpis et commodo pharetra, est eros bibendum elit, nec luctus magna
    felis sollicitudin mauris.
  \end{itemize}
  {\color{gray}\itshape
    \item Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
    nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.}
  \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
  dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
\end{itemize}
```

This works like a charm:

[image]

But I've never seen any advice on how to create a new switch and I'd rather define a nice command instead of hard coding visual formatting.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\existingnotes}[1]{\textit{\textcolor{gray}{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Curabitur pretium tincidunt lacus. Nulla gravida orci a odio. Nullam
    varius, turpis et commodo pharetra, est eros bibendum elit, nec luctus magna
    felis sollicitudin mauris.
  \end{itemize}
  \existingnotes{%
    \item Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
    nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.%
  }
  \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
  dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

## Follow-up

This is for essentially "quoting" old notes in a set of new notes.

I would also like to be able to add new notes into old notes, for this I came up with a simple environment to give me light grey, italic font and also to add a bit of an indent on either side, after all it's a quote. And then a command to give me black, upright text for the new notes:

```
\usepackage{quoting}
\newenvironment{oldnotes}{%
  \begin{quoting}[font=itshape]\color{gray}}{\end{quoting}%
}

\newcommand{\newnotes}[1]{\textnormal{\textcolor{black}{#1}}}
```

I'd been using this happily, without realising there was a flaw with it. As long as I don't nest `itemize` environments, this too works well:

```latex
\begin{oldnotes}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
    eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    \newnotes{%
      \item Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
      nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.%
    }
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
    dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  \end{itemize}
\end{oldnotes}
```

[image]

But, of course, it doesn't work with nested `itemize` environments:

```latex
\begin{oldnotes}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
    eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Curabitur pretium tincidunt lacus. Nulla gravida orci a odio. Nullam
      varius, turpis et commodo pharetra, est eros bibendum elit, nec luctus
      magna felis sollicitudin mauris.
    \end{itemize}
    \newnotes{%
      \item Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
      nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.%
    }
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
    dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  \end{itemize}
\end{oldnotes}
```

[image]

Can anyone help me improve my definitions?

## Bonus marks

Obviously if the `oldnotes` environment could be made to depend on the `\existingnotes` command that would be very elegant as then I could change both at the same time if I decide, say, I would like a slightly different shade of grey. Or if I want to use blue :P

Answer (score 2):

In your case, define it using the switches *within a group*:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\existingnotes}[1]{{\color{gray}\itshape #1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Curabitur pretium tincidunt lacus. Nulla gravida orci a odio. Nullam
    varius, turpis et commodo pharetra, est eros bibendum elit, nec luctus magna
    felis sollicitudin mauris.
  \end{itemize}
  \existingnotes{%
    \item Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
    nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.%
  }
  \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
  dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works excellently. The only downside is I'm not sure how to incorporate your nice new definition of `\newcommand{\existingnotes}[1]{{\color{gray}\itshape #1}}` into a definition of the `oldnotes` environment, to keep them in line with each other

Comment: Okay, I've gone away and had a little think, I came up with this: `\newcommand{\quotednotes}{\color{gray}\itshape}
\newcommand{\existingnotes}[1]{{\quotednotes #1}}
\newcommand{\newnotes}[1]{{\color{black}\upshape #1}}

\usepackage{quoting}
\newenvironment{oldnotes}{%
  \begin{quoting}\quotednotes}{\end{quoting}%
}` Can I expect any nasty surprises or do you think that will about do it?

Comment: @Au101: Using the switches in your way doesn't seem like it would cause an issue.

Comment: :) Thank you for the professional opinion :P